# How to transform the following text to Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The following data is stored in a file which I read by using **readlines()**.

1st June

Breakfast - 20

Lunch - 40

Snacks - 10

Bus Ticket - 130

Auto - 60

3rd June

Bus Ticket- 206

Auto - 71

Rent - 3385

Electricity - 1085

Dinner - 120

I've tried a lot of things but couldn't get the exact output. The **output required** is:

```
         Breakfast  Lunch  Snacks  Bus Ticket  Auto  Rent  Electricity  Dinner
1st June    20       40      10        130      60    0         0         0
3rd June     0        0       0        206      71   3385      1085      120
```

The dates in the data should be the index of the Dataframe followed by the items as column names and the cost as the values of the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""1st June

Breakfast - 20

Lunch - 40

Snacks - 10

Bus Ticket - 130

Auto - 60

3rd June

Bus Ticket - 206

Auto - 71

Rent - 3385

Electricity - 1085

Dinner - 120"""
```

First create `DataFrame` by [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameter `names` if no header of `csv`:

```
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), names=['data'])
print (df)
                  data
0             1st June
1       Breakfast - 20
2           Lunch - 40
3          Snacks - 10
4     Bus Ticket - 130
5            Auto - 60
6             3rd June
7     Bus Ticket - 206
8            Auto - 71
9          Rent - 3385
10  Electricity - 1085
11        Dinner - 120
```

Then create 3 new columns - first repeat dates by forward filling of `NaN`s created by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html), then [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) values and remove unnecessary rows by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
mask = df['data'].str.contains('-')
df['a'] = df['data'].mask(mask).ffill()
df[['b', 'c']] =  df['data'].where(mask).str.split(' - ', expand=True)
df = df.dropna(subset=['b'])
```

Last reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), if necessary original order of values add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and for data cleaning use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = (df.set_index(['a','b'])['c']
        .astype(int)
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .reindex(columns=df['b'].unique())
        .rename_axis(None)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
          Breakfast  Lunch  Snacks  Bus Ticket  Auto  Rent  Electricity  \
1st June         20     40      10         130    60     0            0   
3rd June          0      0       0         206    71  3385         1085   

          Dinner  
1st June       0  
3rd June     120
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Everything worked for me except for the last part where renaming of axis is done. After I execute it, I get only 2 columns with NaN values. reindex(columns=df['a'].unique() gives me only 2 columns.

Comment: @YashGhorpade - oops, need  `.reindex(columns=df['b'].unique())` instread `.reindex(columns=df['a'].unique())`

Comment: @YashGhorpade - It was my typo, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So, if it were me, I would put everything into a dict, and then build a dataframe from that dict. Do your lines of data have any parts that are similar for values of a certain type? Do your index values (`ordinalnumber Month`) differ somehow from your columnar values (`columname - data`)?

Throw those index values into your dict as keys, and then your columnar values into the dict as a list of either tuples or dicts, so like:
`my_pandas_dict = {
"ordNum Month" : 
    {
    "columname" : data,
    "columname" : data,
    "columname" : data,
    ...
    },
...
}`

Then look at the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) to figure out how to make a DataFrame from a dict.

(caveat: I might have organized the data in that dict in a way that isn't `pandas` appropriate. Look at the docs and figure out how to organize it the right way)